# <cfif> a value is in an array without looping?

Tags: coldfusion

This seems like it should be an easy one, but CF seems to have different ways of accomplishing the same thing when it comes to Arrays, so I want to be sure I'm doing it the best way;

I have a simple cfoutput;

```
<cfoutput query="getusers">
Username: #username# ID:#fnid#
</cfoutput>
```

I'm also using cfwebsocket elsewhere on the page, and the value of the 'fnid' (which is a session.auth variable) is part of the subscription.  A dump of wsGetSubscribers gives me the following;

[image]

What I'd like to do is during the output of the 'getusers' query, check to see if the FNID under subscriberinfo.fndid is there - the goal being to add a note to say that user is subscribed at that point.

I know I can do this using a cfloop, but that seems longwinded!

Comment: When you have `<cfoutput query="something">` you have a loop.  Put whatever logic you need between the start and end tags.

Comment: @DanBracuk oh, I know that - but I'm looping through different data there (the query, not the array).  What I'm trying to avoid is having to use cfloop (on the array) within the cfoutput query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm trying to avoid is having to use cfloop (on the array) within the cfoutput query

So you want a kind of look-up for `fnId`? How about:

```html
<cfset subscribersById = StructNew()>

<cfloop array="#wsGetSubscribers()#" index="subsciption">
  <cfset subscribersById[subsciption.subscriberInfo.fnId] = subsciption>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput query="getusers">
  Username: #username# ID: #fnid# Subscribed: #StructKeyExists(subscribersById, fnid)#
</cfoutput>
```

CF10+ has [`arrayEach()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayeach.html) as well, if you prefer this syntax over the `<cfloop>`.